# Mote of Potential and Magic Inspiration

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, bard

I wanted to know whether Magical inspiration used for damage triggers Mote of Potential's Attack:

Magical Inspiration:

> If a creature has a Bardic Inspiration die from you and casts a spell
> that restores hit points or deals damage, the creature can roll that
> die and choose a target affected by the spell. Add the number rolled
> as a bonus to the hit points regained or the damage dealt. The Bardic
> Inspiration die is then lost.

Mote of Potential:

> Attack Roll. Immediately after the creature rolls the Bardic
> Inspiration die to add it to an attack roll against a target, the mote
> thunderously shatters. The target and each creature of your choice
> that you can see within 5 feet of it must succeed on a Constitution
> saving throw against your spell save DC or take thunder damage equal
> to the number rolled on the Bardic Inspiration die.

Answer (score 6):

#### You can use *either* Mote of Potential *or* Magical Inspiration

The feature states (emphasis mine):

> Whenever you give a creature a Bardic Inspiration die, you can utter a note from the Song of Creation to create a Tiny mote of potential [...]
>
> [...] When the creature uses the Bardic Inspiration die, the mote provides an additional effect **based on whether the die benefits an ability check, an attack roll, or a saving throw**, as detailed below: [...]

Magical Inspiration, however, does *not* use the die on an ability check, attack roll, or saving throw. Instead, it uses the Bardic Inspiration die on the casting of a spell itself and modifies its healing/damage. Because of this, Magical Inspiration cannot be used in conjunction with Mote of Potential.

---

Say a creature with Bardic Inspiration on them cast an attack roll spell. They could either choose to add the die to their attack roll, immediately losing the die and immediately causing the "Attack Roll" effect of Mote of Potential, **or** they could choose to use Magical Inspiration, increasing their damage/healing roll for that spell while also immediately losing the die.

Comment: Nice and clear. comments are gone.

Answer (score 1):

### No, it does not.

The mote goes off "immediately after the creature rolls the Bardic Inspiration die to add it to an attack roll".

Since Magical Inspiration adds the die roll "as a bonus to the hit points regained or the damage dealt", not to an attack roll, Magical Inspiration does not meet the triggering condition for Mote of Potential to explode.